Storing long-lived HTTP bearer token for third party API in iOS Keychain
I am building an iOS app that talks to a third party API and supplies a bearer token given to me by the API's developer dashboard. I know storing the token as a string constant within the source code is not secure and research led me to use the iOS Keychain.
I have seen several tutorials explaining how to save and access short-lived tokens that may be generated dynamically (like during log in). However, since my bearer token is long-lived and never changes, I'm confused how I save this key in the keychain without eventually pasting the token as a string in my app? Is the main intended way to provide a login service that delivers the same token to my all users?
Previously, I was building an API Proxy service that uses my API key but wanted to see if bearer tokens could help me avoid having to host a Node.js service.

As you say, the problem is how do you distribute the token to your app users?  Even if you have the users authenticate first and then use an authenticated service to deliver the token you risk the token being disclosed.  A better approach is the one you are already working on; A proxy service that has access to the token and which provides endpoints to authenticated users that make use of the token.
